# How to not use Foundation styling for buttons in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, simple-form

I'm using Foundation in my Rails app.

The `button` class is added to all form buttons when I use `simple_form`.

How can I avoid that without overriding the `button` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` initializer

You can find

```
  # Default class for buttons
  config.button_class = 'button'
```

comment it or change it as you wish